# Remove words shorter than n whatever if there is an hyphen inside or not

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove words with less than 4 characters whatever if there is hyphen or not inside. I mean :

Keep :

"Royaume-Uni"

"ab-cd"

"ab-c"

Remove :

"a-b"

"abc"

"ab-"

I do this with than regex : `replaceAll("\\b[\\w]{1,3}\\b","")`;

but for "Royaume-Uni" for example it gives : "Royaume-" and remove "Uni". I want to keep the entire word.

How could I remove words with less than 4 characters (hyphen considered as one character) and let intact others?

Comment: It is not clear if you want remove also the optional hyphen or take care only of words with less than 4 characters without hiphens

Comment: What do you mean by "take care of that hyphen"? Do you want to remove it, or maybe you see it as proper character in word which should prevent `Uni` from being removed?

Comment: I did an update, tell me if it's not crystal clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` represent place which is

- between alphanumeric (including `_`) and non-alphanumeric characters
- at start or end of your string

So in case of `-U` it matches place represented (by `|`) `-|U`. If you want make your searching based on whitespace and non-whitespace characters then you can't use `\b`. Instead you need to use [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms like

- `(?<=\s|^)` to check if your word has space or start of the string before it,
- `(?=\s|$)`  to check if your word has space or end of the string after it.

Also to consider `-` as part of {1,3} character word use character set which will be sum of `\w` and `-` which can be represented as `[\w-]` (normally `-` is special character inside character class because it can be used to create range of characters like `a-z` but since it can't be used here to represent such range we don't need to escape it).

So your solution can look like:

```
replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)[\\w-]{1,3}(?=\\s|$)","");
```

Comment: Thanks. It well keeps words more than 3 characters but it also keeps "a-b" "-ab" or "ab-". Escaping hyphen brings same result. How could we remove theses 3 characters words ?

Comment: It seems to be working fine https://ideone.com/tSzZFa. I just need to change ^ to $ in one place.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for your skill.

Answer (score 0):

If you would take care also of optional hyphens before and after your match:

```
replaceAll("[-]*\\b[\\w]{1,3}\\b[-]*"," ");
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/eF5n3C/1

On the other hand, if you want match all the words with less of 4 characters but without preceding and leading hyphens, you should add an look around regex before and after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this *(simple)* :

```
replaceAll("\\b-?\\w{1,3}\\b", " ");
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/kbRsj9/4)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the wordboundaries with negative [lookarround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), because there is a wordboundary between dash `-` and letter.

```
(?<![\\w-])\\w{1,3}(?![\\w-])
```

`(?<![\\w-])` means there is no `-` or word character before.
`(?![\\w-])` means there is no `-` or word character after.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. But with something like "a-b" it keeps it. This should be detected as a less than 4 letters word and removed, how could we do such thing ? "\b(\w-\w)\b" this to work only with 3 letters.

Comment: @YesWeStillCan What do you mean by "This seems to work". This solution simply *prevents* deleting 3 or less character words if they have `-` before or after it which kind of conflicts with what you are saying next. Please update your question and clarify what you want to do since ("take care of that hyphen" is not clear enough). You can include some examples showing what should be removed, what shouldn't and why.

Comment: Let me more clear. Actually I want to remove any word that is less than 4 characters whatever if there is hyphen or not inside. So I want to remove "a-b" or "a--" or "-ba" or "abc". But I want to keep "abcd" or "ab-cd".

Comment: @YesWeStillCan Please put that info in your question. Also clarify your logic, because you just said that you want to keep `ab-cd` but in your question you are removing `Uni` in `-Uni` (also your question doesn't state if this is intentional or not and "take care of that hyphen" doesn't help us determine it). So do you want to remove `-Uni` but not `-cd`? What is the logic here? How you decide what should be removed and what not?

Comment: @Pshemo : I did an update. The only parameter is the n characters and hyphen considered as a one character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
(?<=^|[^\w-])[\w-]{1,3}(?=[^\w-]|$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/UUeQLuUqJm).

Essentially `\b` is useless, because dash-then-space is not `\b`. Instead, use look arounds to assert the previous/next chars are not your "hyphenated word chars", or are start/end of input.